# if $K$ is uncountable then $V$ is uncountable , ($V$ non trivial).

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a Vectorspace over the Field $K$.
With $K$ uncountable.

my attempt: we know that multiplication operates $\cdot : K\times V \rightarrow V$ hence for 
$\alpha$ in $K$ and $v$ in $V$ we have $\alpha \cdot v \in V$. 
Now I show: $v \neq 0$ and $\alpha \neq \beta$ then $\alpha v \neq \beta v$.
This is equivalent to showing: $\alpha v= \beta v \Rightarrow \alpha=\beta$.
We have: $\alpha v= \beta v \Rightarrow (\alpha - \beta)v=0 \Rightarrow \alpha=\beta$ since $v \neq 0$.

So for two different elements in $K$ we get two differten elements in $V$ by multiplication ( if $v \neq 0$, wich exists if $V$ not trivial).
Since $K$ is uncountable so must $V$ be.

Is this correct? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, though you should have specified that $V$ is not trivial in the problem statement already.

Comment: thanks a lot. Will add that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's it all (any nonzero $v$ gives the embedding $K\hookrightarrow V,\ \lambda\mapsto \lambda v$). $V$ must be nontrivial.