# Vector space of real numbers over the rational numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

What is the easiest way to show that $\mathbb R$ is not finitely generated over $\mathbb Q$ ?

Comment: What about "finite sum of rational number is rational"?

Comment: $\mathbb Q^n$ is countable

Comment: Another way: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/620465/if-k-is-uncountable-then-v-is-uncountable-v-non-trivial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Eisenstein's criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion) to show that the polynomials $x^{n} - 2$ are irreducible over the rationals. This yields that $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[n]{2}]$ has dimension $n$ over the rationals. So the reals contain subspaces over the rationals of *arbitrarily large* finite dimension.

Comment: In this argument countability is not used. I wondered if this kind of proof can be given. It is very nice, thank you.

Comment: @martin, you're very welcome!

Answer (score 3):

Assume $\mathbb{R} = \mathbb{Q}\langle r_1,\ldots,r_n\rangle.$ The left-hand side is uncountable, whereas the right-hand side is countable.